# Optimizing Performance: Developing MEAN/MERN Stack Applications with Remote Clusters and Skaffold

Tags: performance, kubernetes, skaffold

I'm a MEAN stack developer who primarily works on basic development tasks. I've recently started using Kubernetes, Docker, and microservices for my projects. However, I've encountered performance issues on my local machine when trying to balance the load. To address this, I've purchased a cluster on DigitalOcean.

My question is whether anyone has experience using a similar setup, where they apply local kubectl commands using Skaffold for development and testing. Specifically, I'm curious about how to achieve real-time updates in client-side applications, such as React or Angular, while working with a remote cluster. Is it possible to develop and test in this way using a cluster?

I'm looking for guidance and best practices to ensure a smooth development workflow with this cluster-based setup. Any insights and recommendations would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You might find [mirrord](https://mirrord.dev) useful. It lets you run a local process in connection to a remote Kubernetes cluster, so that you can iterate on a one or two components locally while having everything else running in the cloud.